# Multinomial logistic function in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to replicate results from sklearn's LogisiticRegression classifier for multinomial classes.
This is my code:

```
import math
y = 24.019138
z = -0.439092
print 'Using sklearn predict_proba function: '
print all_classifiers['1'][0].predict_proba([y,z])
print 'Coefficients:'
print all_classifiers['1'][0].coef_
print 'Intercept:'
print all_classifiers['1'][0].intercept_
with_sigmoid = []
for i,j in zip(all_classifiers['1'][0].coef_,all_classifiers['1'][0].intercept_):
    beta1,beta2 = i
    beta0 = j
    a = beta0 + (y*beta1) + (z*beta2)
    b = 1/float(1+math.exp(-a))
    with_sigmoid.append(b)
print 'Using sigmoid function: '
print with_sigmoid
```

This gives me the output:

```
Using sklearn predict_proba function: 
[[  9.03429446e-35   4.91411807e-01   5.08588193e-01]]
Coefficients:
[[ -3.47464867 -15.3518603 ]
[  0.91372436   0.98331135]
[  9.17971403  64.76067487]]
Intercept:
[ -0.99614688 -18.16136032   3.32166197]
Using sigmoid function: 
[1.7763476601257703e-34, 0.9662273209839563, 1.0]
```

The results are different and using sigmoid function the probabilities don't even add up to 1. Considering that it uses one vs all classification, I think this should work. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one vs all classification doesn't have to add up to one. It is three classifiers working on their own, one for each class. However, if you normalize the values given by the one vs all classification, you will get the probabilities given by predict_proba

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> one_vs_all = np.array([1.7763476601257703e-34, 0.9662273209839563, 1.0])
>>> one_vs_all/sum(one_vs_all)
array([  9.03429446e-35,   4.91411807e-01,   5.08588193e-01])
```